# Odd Lambda Syntax in Coq

Tags: lambda, coq

I'm reading through [CPDT](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/toc.html) and there is one example that I'm not understanding:

```
Definition plus_rec : nat -> nat -> nat :=
  nat_rec (fun _ : nat => nat -> nat) (fun m => m) (fun _ r m => S (r m)).
```

Most of this makes sense except for the `fun _ : nat => nat -> nat`. I don't understand how this can have any meaning at all, this function appears to be returning a type with no value.

Am I misunderstanding something fundamental here about Coq? What is the significance of that lambda?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take a look at `nat_rec`:

```
nat_rec :
  forall P : nat -> Set,
  P O ->
  (forall n : nat, P n -> P (S n)) ->
  forall n : nat, P n
```

Its first argument is a `P` which, given a `nat`, returns a `Set`. Then you are going to give an element of the set `P O`, and an element of the set `P (S n)` assuming you have an element from `P n`, and finally with all that, you are given back something of type `forall n, P n` which means it can construct an element of type `P n` for every `n` you pass in as input (if you pass O, it's going to give you back the `P O` you provided, otherwise it's going to build your result by repeated applications of the third argument).

---

Now, that lambda which is confusing you is that `P` I've been talking about. It is given a `nat` and from it builds the "return type". In particular we are trying to have the return type of `nat_rec`, namely `forall n : nat, P n` be the type of `plus_rec`, that is `nat -> nat -> nat`. This can be done by instantiating `P` such that for all n, `P n = nat -> nat`. Which is what we obtain using the lambda-term `fun _ : nat => nat -> nat`.

This term ignores the input `nat` (because `nat_rec` is general enough to build things whose type depend on the first `nat` they receive, but the type of `plus_rec` partially applied to any first argument does not actually depend on the value of that argument). Then it just returns `nat -> nat` (which is the type of the partial application of addition to one operand: we still expect a `nat` before we can return the sum `nat`).

---

Now if you take a look at `nat_rec` partially applied to that funny lambda-term, the type is:

```
nat_rec (fun _ : nat => nat -> nat) :
  (fun _ : nat => nat -> nat) O ->
  (forall n : nat, (fun _ : nat => nat -> nat) n -> (fun _ : nat => nat -> nat) (S n)) ->
  forall n : nat, (fun _ : nat => nat -> nat) n
```

(I just replied `P` with `(fun _ : nat => nat -> nat)`. Now, this simplifies into:

```
nat_rec (fun _ : nat => nat -> nat) :
  (nat -> nat) ->
  (forall n : nat, (nat -> nat) -> (nat -> nat)) ->
  forall n : nat, (nat -> nat)
```

Now this should definitely be confusing.

You should think of the first argument you need to give as the type of the partial application of `plus` to `O`. It receives the second operand, and returns the sum of the two:

```
(fun m => m) (* morally, O + m *)
```

The second argument is given a `(n : nat)`, a function `r : nat -> nat`, another `m : nat`, and needs to return a final `nat`. It is the most confusing in the bunch. Morally, `r` is a `P n`, that is, given our goal, "a function who knows how to add n to its input". Morally again, the last `(nat -> nat)` should be a `P (S n)`, that is "a function who knows how to add (S n) to its input". In particular, we named this input `m`. You should be able to convince yourself that the result should be:

```
(fun _ r m => S (r m))
(* ignore n, use r (which is the "+ n" function) on m, to get (n + m), and add 1 to get (n + 1) + m *)
```

With all this, we managed to build the function `plus`.

---

Note that is a very error-prone way to define `plus_rec`, in particular because you have to remember really hard what is what or you're not going to define the function you want, because the typing is really loose (see how we ignore the `n` most of the time). In fact, there was a bug in an earlier draft of that same function, which did type-check.

I believe this is shown as to show how everything is under the rug, but do not think that this is the way you should define plus_rec in general.

---

Finally, this is quite hard to explain and I am pretty sure my answer will not be crystal-clear. Feel free to drop comments and I'll edit the answer to make things more clean.

Comment: Thanks for the informative reply! So this function is kind of type level? ie It's meant to be used in type signatures, not for constructing values?

Comment: Yes, it does indeed return a type as indicated by its return type being `Set`. It just so happens to always return the same type, `nat -> nat`, regardless of its input.